# working with canvas : The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Tags: android, imageview, android-linearlayout

I visit so many solutions regarding this issue but can't catch it clearly .When ever I run the project first time it works perfectly but when I run it second time then it fire this error in logCat

```
     The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first
```

where is the `error` in that code segment ?where should I change in code. any suggestion is acceptable .Thanks in advance ..
`Main.java`

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    List<PieDetailsItem> piedata = new ArrayList<PieDetailsItem>(0);

    EditText edt3;
    Button btnChart;
    public String s15;
    public String[] strArray;
    public ImageView mImageView ;
    public LinearLayout finalLayout ;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        finalLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.pie_container);
        mImageView = new ImageView(this);

        edt3 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        btnChart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);




        btnChart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                /*if(mImageView != null) { 
                    finalLayout.removeView(mImageView); 
                    }
                else {*/

                 s15 = edt3.getText().toString();


                /*System.out.println("value 1 is  --->"+s10);
                System.out.println("value 2 is  --->"+s12);*/

                System.out.println("value 3 is  --->"+s15);


                 String domain = s15;
                 strArray = domain.split("\\,");
                 for (String str : strArray) {
                  System.out.println(str);
                 }
            //  }
                 openChart();

            }
        });

    }

    private void openChart(){ 

        Integer[] items = new Integer[strArray.length];

        //double[] distribution = new double[strArray.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            items[i] = Integer.parseInt(strArray[i]);

            System.out.println("xxxxxx"+items[i]);
        }

        PieDetailsItem item;
        int maxCount = 0;
        int itemCount = 0;
    //  int items[] = { 20, 40, 10, 15, 5 };

        int colors[] = { -6777216, -16776961, -16711681, -12303292, -7829368 };
        // String itemslabel[] = { " vauesr ur 100", " vauesr ur 200",
        // " vauesr ur 300", " vauesr ur 400", " vauesr ur 500" };

        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            itemCount = items[i];
            item = new PieDetailsItem();
            item.count = itemCount;
            // item.label = itemslabel[i];
            item.color = colors[i];
            piedata.add(item);
            maxCount = maxCount + itemCount;
        }
        int size = 200;
        int BgColor = 0xffa11b1;
        Bitmap mBaggroundImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        View_PieChart piechart = new View_PieChart(this);
        piechart.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(size, size));
        piechart.setGeometry(size, size, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2130837504);
        piechart.setSkinparams(BgColor);
        piechart.setData(piedata, maxCount);
        piechart.invalidate();

        piechart.draw(new Canvas(mBaggroundImage));
        piechart = null;

        //ImageView mImageView = new ImageView(this);
        mImageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        mImageView.setBackgroundColor(BgColor);
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(mBaggroundImage);
        //LinearLayout finalLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.pie_container);

        finalLayout.addView(mImageView);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding mImageView to the layout multiple times.  A view can only be part of 1 ViewGroup.  You need to either add it only once, or create a second ImageView if you really want 2 of them in the layout.

Comment: where should i change ?? i want to refresh view when i press ok button .@Gabe Sechan .

Comment: The last line of openChart-  you only want to add the image view if it hasn't already been added.

Comment: yup .correct but i added it as u can see in that method ,so now where should i change ?

Comment: @jill Add this line **finalLayout.removeView(mImageView);** for first line of  openChart() method

Comment: i got it ..thanx a lot :) and have you ever work with pie chart ? ?? i need suggestion that how to display values of the portion in piechart with percantage (like 12,12%) .in that particular portion of chart .@Kalyan pvs